# Slice does not work after using .split() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that takes the "day" part of a Y-M-D date string.
For example:
Input: ["2022 November 23,2023 April 9"]
Output: 23

I have tried to do this by using the .split() function to split the string up at the comma, then slicing the last 2 indexes out to get the day. However, while I can get the last term of the new split string easily, I cannot get the 2nd-to-last term.

Ex:

```
    y_m_d="2022 November 20,2023 April 9"
    split_ymd=y_m_d.split(",")
    first_value=split_ymd[0]
    print(split_ymd[-1]) #This prints "0"
```

However, adding the 2nd argument to the slice command breaks it

```
    y_m_d="2022 November 20,2023 April 9"
    split_ymd=y_m_d.split(",")
    first_value=split_ymd[0]
    print(split_ymd[-1:-2]) #This prints "[]"
```

I understand that some of the terminologies above might not be correct as I a new to learn python, and programming in general, and that the code above is **very** messy but I just need help knowing why the slice command above does not work. I am open to suggestions on improving the code itself, but I really just want to know why the slice does not work in his situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Think of the relation between `a_list[start:stop:step]` and `range(start, stop, step)` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slice doesn't work in this situation because the slice doesn't work in any situation. It's unrelated to `.split()` or anything else you're doing.

Consider this simpler test case:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4][-1]
4
>>> [1,2,3,4][-1:-2]
[]
```

This happens because `-1` refers to index 3 and -2 refers to index 2, and the span `[3,2)` is backwards so it's treated as empty.

You can swap them if you actually want a range:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4][-2:-1]
[3]
```

Or you can just use `-2` if you want the second-from-last element:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4][-2]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your initial list on the comma to create a list containing
multiple strings, each representing a date.

Then iterate over those dates, splitting them by spaces. The last value in the subsequent list is the day value you are looking for.

Let me know if this isn't clear.

It looks something like this:

```
list_of_dates = ["2022 November 23, 2023 April 9"] 

# This separates all dates by splitting on the comma
dates = "".join(list_of_dates).split(",")

days = []
for d in dates:
    # This splits each date on the space
    temp = d.split(" ")
    days.append(temp[-1])

print(days)
# Output: ["23", "9"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have two recommendations here:

1. Try learning how python slicing works (both negative and positive numbers)
2. For your actual solution, I see a list of dates. Comma separating it and then parsing the date into a datetime object might make things easier here.

```
# For example,
date_str_list = "2022 November 20,2023 April 9"
for date_str in date_str_list.split(","):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y %B %d")
    day = date.day
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html for more details on how you can control the string format of a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this in a few different ways:

1. Using the len function:

> ```
> date = "2013 November 20,2023 April 10"     
> splitted = date.split(',')
> splitted[0][len(splitted[0])-2:]
> ```

2. Use negative indexing:

> ```
> date = "2013 November 20,2023 April 10"    
> splitted = date.split(',')
> splitted[0][-2:]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

#### The Amazing `datetime` Module!

First lesson: **Let the built-ins do the hard work for you!**

Here is an example of your function which parses a date string and returns the day.  Additionally, here is an example implementation of how you can use the function.

Hope this helps!

#### The Function:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def extract_day(date_string, mask='%Y %B %d'):
    """Extract and return the day.

    Args:
        date_string (str): Date text as a string.
        mask (str): Format of the provided date string, 
            used for parsing.

    """
    day = dt.strptime(date_string, mask).day
    return day
```

#### Implementation:

```
dates1 = "2022 November 20,2023 April 9"
dates2 = "20 Nov 2022,9 Apr 2023"

date_strings1 = dates1.split(',')
date_strings2 = dates2.split(',')

for date in date_strings1:
    day = extract_day(date)
    print('\nOriginal string: {}'.format(date))
    print('Extracted day: {}'.format(day))

for date in date_strings2:
    day = extract_day(date, mask='%d %b %Y')
    print('\nOriginal string: {}'.format(date))
    print('Extracted day: {}'.format(day))
```

#### Output:

```
Original string: 2022 November 20
Extracted day: 20

Original string: 2023 April 9
Extracted day: 9

Original string: 20 Nov 2022
Extracted day: 20

Original string: 9 Apr 2023
Extracted day: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ymd="2022 November 20,2023 April 9"
lchar = ymd.find(',')
fchar = lchar-2
d_int = int(y_m_d[fchar:lchar])
print(d_int)
```

If there is only one comma after the date this should give you what you want.